# closed form of series involving gamma function

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, gamma-function

**In one of my calculation, I came across the series:**
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{n}}{Γ(n\alpha)}$$
$0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function

Comment: **thank you for advice.**

Comment: At $n=0$ the denominator is undefined.